# jQuery UI dialog with AJAX not runing click function for the second time

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I have a strange bug with jQuery UI dialog & AJAX.

This is the process:

1. click on link > link open div with AJAX.
2. in AJAX div click on link > open jQuery UI dialog with another AJAX.
3. click on link in jQuery UI AJAX dialog > do `alert()` message with JavaScript.

Now I do the same process right from the start, Everything works fine until the stage of the `alert()` message.
So if i do the process next time step 3 not work and im not get any error in my console.

[image]

Code for step 2 (open jQuery UI dialog with AJAX):

```
function update_link(rel)
{
   $("#update_link").dialog({
            modal: false,
            height: 370,
            width: 900,
            title: 'im title',
            open: function () {
                $(this).load("<?= site_url()?>/links/show_update?id="+rel+"&rand="+rand());

            }
     });

}
```

Code to get the alert message in step 3 (this code is in the jQuery UI dialog page):

```
$("#to_page_home").on("click", function (){
    alert("im not work if you open me in AJAX again!");
});
```

If I do this instead of code, it also doesn't work:

```
<a href="#" id="to_page_home" onclick="alert('im not work if you open me in AJAX again!');">
```

Thank you all and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1):

Do you toggle #to_page_home at any point?  If that ID disappears/reappears, your on() won't re-register when it re-appears

Look at the [Direct and Delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/) section of the doc . . . you'll probably need something like this:

```
$("#parentContainer").on("click", "#to_page_home', function (){
    alert("im not work if you open me in AJAX again!");
});
```

In this case, the element with ID parentContainer would have to contain the element with to_page_home, and would have to be permanently on the page.

Comment: Sorry, I had a mistake in the code.  `onclick()` won't work either, for the same reason as mentioned before - if `#to_page_home` is being removed from the page, and re-added, the event handlers will not re-register on it.

Comment: What should be my `#parentContainer`? the dialog?

Comment: i try this code: 
`$("#update_link").on("click", "#to_page_home", function (){
  alert("msg");
 });`

This code also does not work

Comment: #parentContainer needs to be a permanent aspect on the page, present when it's first loaded.  If #update_link goes away and is re-added, then it won't work.  As stated before, please read and try to understand about Delegated events.

Comment: i understand what is Delegated, but i don't think this is relevant to my problem.
I even tried to give the div a random name every time that AJAX change.
But nothing works.

Comment: If you're giving it a random name, it's a new element, and the handler won't attach.  You never answered the question of if the #to_page_home element toggles or not, though it sounds like it does, so when it's removed and re-added, the jQuery handler will not re-attach to it.  This is probably why it works once, and then stops working, and why you need to attach to a parent element (which is permanently on the page), and then filter for the child using a delegated event.